# Multiple of $p$ in first $p+1$ Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Defining $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ and $F_{n+1} = F_{n} + F_{n-1}$ for $n>0$ gives the Fibonacci sequence, and it is well-known that modulo $p$, one of the first $p+1$ terms is $0.$ In fact, more is known, but what I'm interested in is whether there is a proof that does not rely on quadratic reciprocity/Binet's formula of this fact; more specifically, if there is a proof whose main ingredient is pigeonhole. Pigeonhole at least tells you that within the first $(p-1)^2+1$ terms, this is true, since you can just look at pairs of residue classes mod $p,$ but is there a way to get down to $p+1$?